# How to keep existing file selections on multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

In html we can select multiple files at once using file input control. But when i selected a file second time previous files overwritten by the newly selected files.

My question is, Can we able to keep existing file selections while selecting new files?

Comment: Is this in a grid? or do ou have checkboxes or something next to the stuff you want to select?

Comment: I just want to select files from different directories.

Comment: so you are using <input type='file' name='userFile'>?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get any snippet related to this, seems most people doesn't require this kind of functionality. So i did it myself.

- created a file input control
- click event on this element, clones **current file input** with duplicate id using jquery `clone` method. This cloned input control set to hidden and current input control holds latest files.
- so, on form submit i got all the files selected

I doubt how well this method works in older browsers, but current chrome and firefox executes it well.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think your problem is that you give the same name to the different <input> tags.

<div id="selectFiles">
    <input type='file' name='userFile1'>
    <input type='file' name='userFile2'>
    <input type='file' name='userFile3'>
    <input type='file' name='userFile4'>
</div>
```

Comment: no frederik, i have an file input, first time i select files using that, selected files are listed. if i again click on that control and select some other files it is listing files what i selected second time. i need all files...

Comment: You are overwriting the previous selected file. It thinks you dont want it anymore and that you want to select another file in its place. thats how that works. else you can use jQuery or pure javascript to have that, then you select a file. then a button that says "Add To List". when you click that button, it takes the path of the selected file and adds it to some list. you can use jQuery to add more tags to some child tags when you do this. than upon uploading you loop and retrieve the text from the tags. thats all i can think of. but the way you are trying to do it is not gona work.